# PHP - Memcache for aprox. 20k small strings - out of memory

Tags: php, memcached

I have created simple code with memcache

```
function CreateMemcacheName()
{
    //lat and lon are latitude and longitude of place
    //user can not directly change this - it is passed from image URL
    //embeded in HTML site
    $lat = intval($_GET['lat'] * 100);
    $lon = intval($_GET['lon'] * 100);
    return "data_{$lat}_{$lon}";
}


function LoadData($memcache)
{

    $name = CreateMemcacheName(); //crate unique name based on URL params

    if (is_null($memcache) == false)
    {
        $data = $memcache->get($name);

        if ($data !== false)
        {
            return $data;
        }
    }

    $data = DownloadDataFromAPI();
    //data are around 10kb

    if (is_null($memcache) == false)
    {
        $memcache->set($name, $data, 0, 1 * 60 * 60);
    }

    return $data;
}


$memcache = new Memcache();
if ($memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211))
{
   $data = $this->LoadData($memcache);
}
```

This code is called for every user, that visits the site. There are approximatelly 20k combinations, that can come from `CreateMemcacheName`. If I use this, server goues out of memory very soon. Without memcache, all is running OK, but `DownloadDataFromAPI` is called to often and leading to depleading of API resources I have.

However, when I compute max. size (20k * 10kb) it way below my server free memory. So, what should I improve? Or use database with my own timestamp indicating old data instead of memcache.

Comment: You don't say what environment you're working with, but on Ubuntu systems, memcached's memory limit defaults to only 64MB, while you would need roughly 200MB to store 20,000 ~10KB strings. This answer explains how to change the limit for both Ubuntu and Redhat systems: https://serverfault.com/questions/202017/how-to-increase-the-amount-of-memory-memcache-uses

Comment: I have CentOS 7. Memcache can accomodate data, problem is server. My entire RAM is gone in minutes.

Comment: Are you sure that `CreateMemcacheName()` is creating consistent names or is it always generating a new name.  This could mean that you never get a cache hit and continually store the same data.

Comment: Since it is taking data from URL, I am quite sure.

Comment: Sorry to ask something simple, but can you give an example of what  `CreateMemcacheName()` is generating.  Or if you fix it  to something simple, is it getting a hit and therefore it's managing to get and set the data from memcache OK.

Comment: @NigelRen Edited question